# Week to Day Interpolation

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a weekly timeseries to a daily format.

The original data looks like this

[image: Picture of the original Dataframe]

With

```
set$Date <- as.Date(paste(set$YEAR, set$WEEK, 1, sep="-"),"%Y-%U-%u")
```

I have been able to convert the "YEAR"/"WEEK" columns into the standard ISO-Date-Format, for the first day of the corresponding week!

[image: Dataframe after Date-Transformation]

Now I tried to interpolate the observations regionwise

```
Virginia <- data.frame(set[set$REGION=="Virginia",5],set[set$REGION=="Virginia",4])
Virginia <- na.omit(Virginia)
colnames(Virginia) <- c("Date","ILI")
```

[image: Regionselected Dataframe]

The interpolation yields:

```
library(tempdisagg)

t_d <- td(Virginia ~ 1, conversion = "mean", to = "day", method = "denton-cholette")

[time]: 'Date' [value]: 'ILI' 
    Error in td(Virginia ~ 1, conversion = "mean", to = "day", method = "denton-cholette") : 
      left hand side contains NAs
```

Which puzzles me, since I omitted any NAs beforehand.
In the region-selected dataframe the "Date"-column is of the type "Date" and the "ILI"-column of the type "numeric", so no irregularities there.

Any Ideas what went wrong?

My second approach was to create a daily series of NAs, plug the weekly onto the corresponding dates and use the "na.approx" function from the "zoo" package to approximate the NAs. This proved equally challenging since the number of NAs greatly exceeds the number of given observations.

[image]

**Reproducibility**

Structure-Code on GitHub:

[Dataframe](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperinfer/ILI/main/Dataframe)

Complete Code:

```
set$Date <- as.Date(paste(set$YEAR, set$WEEK, 1, sep="-"),"%Y-%U-%u")

library(tempdisagg)

Virginia <- data.frame(set[set$REGION=="Virginia",5],set[set$REGION=="Virginia",4])
Virginia <- na.omit(Virginia)
colnames(Virginia) <- c("Date","ILI")

t_d <- td(Virginia ~ 1, conversion = "mean", to = "day", method = "denton-cholette")
```

Comment: I just did now! Sorry, it took me a bit to figure out how best to share the original data with you!

Comment: What is your expected/desired results?

Comment: I would like to have daily observations instead of weekly!
Right now I only have observations for weeks 40, 41, 42, (...).

Comment: Instead of posting a link to the entire data set, can you post the results of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`?

Comment: structure(list(REGION = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado"), YEAR = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010), WEEK = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), UNWEIGHTED.ILI = c(2.13477, 
0.875146, 0.674721, 0.696056, 1.95412, 0.660684)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: So, I'm not really familiar with this package, but based on the documentation, it looks like you need to have the `tsbox` package installed to do frequencies other than monthly or quarterly

Answer (score 0):

Alright it seems like my date-transformation

```
set$Date <- as.Date(paste(set$YEAR, set$WEEK, 1, sep="-"),"%Y-%U-%u")
```

yields an unfit result for the td()-function.

The original data is recorded for the timespan "2010-10-04" to "2021-07-12" in weeks.

If I create the same sequence via

```
seq(as.Date("2010-10-04"),as.Date("2021-07-12"),"week")
```

and just put this and the numerics from the data into a separate dataframe (Which apparently gives exactly the same dataframe as "Virginia" above.)

```
test <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2010-10-04"),as.Date("2021-07-12"),"week"),Virginia[,2])
```

and the interpolation works!

Moral of the story: Apparently date transformations should better not be done using "paste", as this is not the first time I had serious problems using this date.